# Servicio de mi aplicación se ejecuta al cerrar la app ¿Cómo evitarlo?

Tags: java, android, xml

estoy actualizando una aplicación de android que inicializa un servicio al hacer login, pero se vuelve a inicailizar cuando cierras la aplicación y empiza a correr duplicado el servicio.

Nota: No hay codigo que lanze el servio con los metodos onDestroy()

Asi esta declarado en el Manifiesto:

```
<service
    android:name="com.MiPaquete.MiAplicacion.MiServicio"
    android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

Comment: Es importante verificar tu clase MiServicio, la podrías agregar, al menos onStartCommand()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se crea un duplicado, de hecho para que tu servicio continué ejecutándose en segundo plano cuando cierras la aplicación seguramente estas usando la propiedad **START_STICKY**, esto dentro del  método `onStartCommand()` :

> **Service.START_STICKY** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.

```
public class MyServide extends Service {

...
...

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Para que se detenga tu servicio al cerrar la aplicación usa **START_NOT_STICKY**

```
return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

---